# jQuery hover and active state

Tags: jquery

I'm having some problems trying to make the hover and active state work on my website. I'm new to jQuery and I'm finding it difficult. 
This is the code that I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.st_tab').hover(function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({opacity : '0', left: '+=50',}, 100);
   }, function(){$(this).stop().animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 500);})

});
```

I want it to work like this example : http://www.queness.com/resources/html/fadein/index.html

I created a test page of site and you can see it here: http://jm-ai.com/test/index.html

I'm using a sprite image for the normal, hover, and active state.

The problem is that whenever I hover the animation disappears too quickly and when I click there is no animation.

Comment: In your example you set the opacity to "0" when you hover a button... this should answer, why it disapears. And if you need an animation when clicked, you should listen to the "click" event not to the "hover" event

Comment: It appears you're trying to set the opacity on the link/anchor itself. In the example you want to mimic, they use a separate div and do the animations on that div(with its associated background image), placing the div under the anchor using positioning. Also, as Luke points out, it appears you have the order reversed for animating the opacity.

Comment: it also appears that you've switched up the functions... i tried running it this way: $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.st_tab').hover(
 function(){
  $(this).css({ 'opacity':1 }).animate({'opacity' : '0'}, 500);
 },
 function(){
  $(this).animate({opacity : '1', left: '+=50',}, 1000);
 })
});

Comment: Note: you have an extraneous trailing comma at the end of `left: '+=50',` This is a common mistake which will throw an error in IE. In other browsers, you'll get a warning and the code will still work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend mouseover mouseout. Make it fill a variable true false whenever it have been clicked.

```
$('.st_tab').mouseover(function() { //animation }).mouseout(function() { //animation });
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick reply!! I'm using the example that Kristian suggested.. It works fine but the problem is that whenever you hover, the hover state appears for a second and then disappears and if you hover the same li the hover state will appear back for 3 seconds and then it disappears. The active state is working fine. Hope any of you could help me with this. Link to my test site: http://jm-ai.com/test/index.html

Comment: Jonas m .. Thanks for your reply.. I tried what you suggested.. It worked but it has the same problem as the example Kristian suggested..   This is what I did with your example :$(document).ready(function(){ $('.st_tab').mouseover(function() { $(this).css({ 'opacity':1 }).animate({'opacity' : '0'}, 500); }).mouseout(function(){ $(this).animate({opacity : '1'}, 1000); }) });